# Permute a string to print all possible words

Tags: python, algorithm

The code that i have written seems to be looking bad with asymptotic measure of running time and space 
I am getting
T(N) = T(N-1)*N + O((N-1!)*N) where N is the size of input. I need advise to optimize it

Since it is an algorithm based interview question we are required to implement the logic in most efficient way without using any libraries

Here is my code

```
def str_permutations(str_input,i):
    if len(str_input) == 1:
        return [str_input]
    comb_list = []
    while i < len(str_input):
        key = str_input[i]
        if i+1 != len(str_input):
            remaining_str = "".join((str_input[0:i],str_input[i+1:]))
        else:
            remaining_str = str_input[0:i]
        all_combinations = str_permutations(remaining_str,0)
        for index,value in enumerate(all_combinations):
            all_combinations[index] = "".join((key,value))
        comb_list.extend(all_combinations)
        i = i+1
    return comb_list
```

Comment: Could you solve the recurrence relation? I forgot how to do that. Also, when you say "permute ... to print all ... combinations", I assume you don't actually mean combinations (since there's only 1 n-combination of an n element set) and instead you mean all permutations? Given that there are n! permutations of a string over n distinct (!) letters, you won't get below exponential complexity in the general case (neither time nor space); you can however count for each character the number of appearances before actually creating permutations.

Comment: Say k_i is the number of appearances of letter i in your string; counting the appearances beforehand (linear time and space using a histogram) you'll save a factor of "product over k_i! for all characters i in the string" (note the factorial).

Comment: @G.Bach thanks for the reply i guess it is difficult recurrence to solve but i agree with u that since the question requires all permutations it can't be less than n! and there will definitely some more complexity for a running program but my program's running time looks really bad i guess

Comment: @G.Bach what did u mean by - "you can however count for each character the number of appearances before actually creating permutations" my solution is with assumption that the characters are unique

Comment: I'll post it in an answer, that's a little more than is sensible to post in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to the question, in the general case you won't get below exponential complexity since for `n` distinct characters, there are `n!` permutations of the input string, and O(2<sup>n</sup>) is a subset of O(n!).

Now the following won't improve the asymptotic complexity for the general case, but you can optimize the brute-force approach of producing all permutations for strings that have some characters with multiple occurrences. Take for example the string `daedoid`; if you blindly produce all permutations of it, you'll get every permutation `6 = 3!` times since you have three occurrences of `d`. You can avoid that by first eliminating multiple occurrences of the same letter and instead remembering how often to use each letter. So if there is a letter `c` that has k<sub>c</sub> occurrences, you'll save k<sub>c</sub>! permutations. So in total, this saves you a factor of "product over k<sub>c</sub>! for all c".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to write your own, see [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: thanks @John for the link i will read through them but since it is an interview question we need to write the logic